# js keybourd function - event is undefined

Tags: javascript

what wrong in this code? why console.log(evt) returns 'undefined'?

this is my code:

```
var documentKeydown = (evt)=>{
        console.log(evt);
        if (counter == 0) {
            XWhenDown = currentX;
            YWhenDown = currentY;
            document.onkeyup = documentKeyup();
            switch (evt.keyCode) {
                case 37 : currentX -= 10; break;
                case 38 : currentY -= 10; break;
                case 39 : currentX += 10; break;
                case 40 : currentY += 10; break;
            }
            animationTick = Ticker.add(animation);
        }
    }

    document.onkeydown = documentKeydown();
```

Comment: you need to let the `keydown` event call your function by assigning it a reference of your function (ie: use `document.onkeydown = documentKeydown`, or `addEventListener`)

Comment: Please add your HTML code to understand the real issue

Comment: @Nick Thanks a lot! I removed the parenthesis and it works perfect: "document.onkeydown = documentKeydown;"

Comment: this may works for you : `document.addEventListener("keydown", documentKeydown);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be `document.onkeydown = documentKeydown;`

not `document.onkeydown = documentKeydown();`

`documentKeydown` is a function so do not need add `()` to call

```js
var documentKeydown = (evt)=> {
  console.log(evt);
}
document.onkeydown = documentKeydown;
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call your function only when an event happens:

```
var documentKeydown = ()=>{
    console.log(event);
    if (counter == 0) {
        XWhenDown = currentX;
        YWhenDown = currentY;
        document.onkeyup = documentKeyup();
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 37 : currentX -= 10; break;
            case 38 : currentY -= 10; break;
            case 39 : currentX += 10; break;
            case 40 : currentY += 10; break;
        }
        animationTick = Ticker.add(animation);
    }
 }

document.addEventListener('keydown', documentKeydown) ;
```

Comment: @NickParsons, I think both ways are possible but what you suggested is straightforward. Have tested both. Will edit the answer though.